# how to pause and resume @KafkaListener using spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have implemented the Kafka consumer, now I have a scenario.

1. Read data from the Kafka stream 2.2.5.Release via Srpingboot
2. load in the database table1
3. copy the data from table1 to table2
4. clear the table1

To do the above things, I need to pause/resume the Kafka consumer using a scheduling job(already written) using quartz, which copies data from table 1 to table 2. But during this activity, I want my Kafka listener to pause, and once the copy is done, it should resume.

My implementation:

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions =
    { @TopicPartition(topic = "data_pipe", partitions = { "0" })})
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 21):

if you use 'kafkaListener annotation' auto created KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry bean, so, You can use it like this code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaManager {

    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    public KafkaManager(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }
    public void pause() {
        registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(MessageListenerContainer::pause);
    }

    public void resume() {
        registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(MessageListenerContainer::resume);
    }
}
```

document : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#pause-resume

Comment: Who or what causes the pause and how to trigger the resume, after data is copied

Comment: That's up to your code; if you give your `@KafkaListener` an `id`, you can use `registry.getListenerContainer(myId).pause()`.

Comment: I have tried above class, and printing the values in logs in both pause and resume method. but they are never called.

Comment: What do you mean by "printing the values in logs"? Edit your question to show your current code that you have tried.

Comment: I had no luck with haulting the @KafkaListener yet